# Uma rota para sempre o mesmo controller mais diversas funções

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte link `meusite.com/admin/concursos/concursos`.
Minhas pastas dentro do `controllers` estão assim:

```
-admin
  +atos
  -concursos
    ->concursos.php
  +licitacoes
```

Este link leva a função `index` do `controller`, `admin` e a pasta do painel administrativo, `concursos` e a pasta para o `controller`, e o ultimo `concursos` do link e o `controller` `concursos.php`.

Se eu crio a rota `$route['admin/concursos/'] = 'admin/concursos/concursos';` ele me leva pelo link `meusite.com/admin/concursos` normal ate o `index`, mais preciso que está mesma rota sempre me leve para outras funções sem ter que ficar criando uma rota para uma função nova como por exemplo: `meusite.com/admin/concursos/visualizar/1`, `meusite.com/admin/concursos/editar/1`.

Existe a possibilidade de uma rota responder a todos esse links?

Comment: Você poderia detalhar melhor?

Comment: @RenatoSilva Fiz uma pequena edição. Mais acredito que expliquei bem, as vezes e complicado entender por você não estar bem iterado na situação.

Comment: @RenatoSilva Mais assim para que sempre eu não precisar adicionar uma rota nova toda vez que eu for acessar uma função diferente. Porque se eu defino esta rota `$route['admin/concursos/'] = 'admin/concursos/concursos'` ela so vai acessar a função index deste `controller`, mais preciso que está rota sempre atenda a outras funções como `admin/concursos/visualizar/5`.

Comment: @RenatoSilva Estou no Codeigniter 3.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
$route['admin/concursos'] = 'admin/concursos/concursos';
$route['admin/concursos/(.*)'] = 'admin/concursos/concursos/$1';
```

A primeira rota indica que sempre que usar a `url` `admin\concursos` vai me levar para o `index` do `controller`, já a segunda rota indica que posso especificar a função que vou chamar dentro do `controller`.

Posso fazer também somente da seguinte maneira:

```
$route['admin/concursos/(.*)'] = 'admin/concursos/concursos/$1';
```

Mais ai preciso informar `index` na `url` `admin\concursos\index`